# R -- Simulate sigmoidally correlated covariates

Tags: r, variables, simulation, correlation

I am attempting to simulate two weight and age values for a population of children. These data should be sigmoidally correlated such that at low ages weight changes slowly, then by approximately 30 weeks postmenstrual age there is an acceleration in weight gain, which begins to level off past about 50 weeks.

I have been able to use the code below to get a linear correlation between weight and age to work fairly well.  The part I am having trouble with is adapting this code to get a more sigmoidal shape to the data.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

---

```
# Load required packages
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)

# Set the number of simulated data points
n <- 100

# Set the mean and standard deviations for
# the two variables
mean_age <- 50
sd_age <- 20

mean_wt <- 10
sd_wt <- 4

# Set the desired level of correlation
# between the two variables
cor_agewt <- 0.9

# Build the covariance matrix
covmat <- matrix(c(sd_age^2, cor_agewt * sd_age * sd_wt,
                   cor_agewt * sd_age * sd_wt, sd_wt^2),
                 nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

# Simulate the correlated results
res <- mvrnorm(n, c(mean_age, mean_wt), covmat)

# Reorganize the simulate data into a data frame
df <- data.frame(age = res[,1],
                 wt = res[,2])

# Plot the results and fit a loess spline
# to the data
ggplot(df, aes(x = age, y = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = 'loess')
```

Current output:
[image: Current output]

Ideal output (albeit over a smaller range of ages and weights):
[image: Ideal output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to specify the functional form between weight and age more specific than just a single correlation. After specifying the functional form of weight~age+e you just draw (age,e) and then calculate the weight. A simple example follows:

```
set.seed(1234)
mean_age <- 50; sd_age <- 20
mean_wt <- 3.5; sd_wt <- 2.2
n<-400

age.seq<-rnorm(n,mean_age,sd_age)
age.seq<-age.seq[order(age.seq)]
#functional form: (here a "logistic" with a a location and scale)   
f<-function(x,loc,sca) 1/(1+exp(-(x-loc)/sca))
wt<-f(age.seq,65,20) #wt
m<-mean_wt/mean(wt) #simple adjustment of the mean
sdfit<-sqrt( sd_wt^2-var(m*wt) )
sim_wt<-m*wt+rnorm(n,0,sdfit) #simulated wt
plot(age.seq,sim_wt)
lines(age.seq,m*wt)
```

[image]
with mean & sd:

```
>sd(age.seq); sd(sim_wt); mean(sim_wt); mean(age.seq) #check
[1] 20.29432
[1] 2.20271
[1] 3.437339
[1] 50.1549
```

:::::: EDIT partially wrt. comment::::::

A restriction on the samplespace, eg. nonzero criteria for weights, gonna make the problem much harder. But if you drop the mean+sd restriction on weights, then it's easy to extend the example to a flexible specification of the functional-form. Following, is a simple example using a truncated normal-dist.:

```
set.seed(1234)

mean_age<-30
sd_age<-10
n<-500

#ex. of control of functional-form
loc<-40 #location 
scale<-10 #scaling
sd_wt <- 0.8 #in the truncated normal 
ey_min<-c(0,0.2) #in the truncated normal
ey_max<-c(55,6) #in the truncated normal

age.seq<-rnorm(n,mean_age,sd_age)
#age.seq<-0:55
n<-length(age.seq)

age.seq<-age.seq[order(age.seq)]
#functional form: (here a "logistic" with a a location and scale)   
f<-function(x,loc,sca) 1/(1+exp(-(x-loc)/sca))

wt<-f(age.seq,loc,scale) #wt
#correct lower:
corr_lower<-ey_min[2]-f(ey_min[1],loc,scale) #add. correction lower
wt<-wt+corr_lower

#correct upper
mult<-(ey_max[2]-ey_min[2])/(f(ey_max[1],loc,scale)+corr_lower) #mult. correction 
wt<-ey_min[2]+wt*mult*(age.seq/ey_max[1])

plot(age.seq,wt,type="l",ylim=c(0,8)) #plot mean used as par in the truncated normal
sim_wt<-truncnorm::rtruncnorm(n,0,,mean=wt,sd=sd_wt)
points(age.seq,sim_wt)

abline(h=0.2,col=2);abline(v=0,col=2)
abline(h=6,col=2);abline(v=55,col=2)
```

which gives (red lines illustrating the controls):
[image]

Of course you could also try control the variance wrt. age, simplified:

```
plot(age.seq,wt,type="l",ylim=c(0,8)) #plot mean used as par in the truncated normal
sim_wt<-truncnorm::rtruncnorm(n,0,,mean=wt,sd=sd_wt*seq(0.3,1.3,len=n))
points(age.seq,sim_wt)
```

[image]
The point here is, that you need more structure to simulate specific data like that (not going into ex. bootstrap methods), eg. there is no internal R-function to the rescue. Of course it get's harder to sample from the distribution when introducing more restrictions. You can always consult Cross Validated for different approaches, choice of distribution etc.

Comment: Excellent -- this works brilliantly. Do you know if it is possible to constrain the simulated values of weight to be positive without decreasing the standard deviation?

Comment: You are welcome. It's possible, but it's not an easy fix and makes your problem a lot more difficult than first stated. Replacing the normal error with a truncated normal will probably get you close, eg. `sim_wt<-truncnorm::rtruncnorm(n,0,,mean=m*wt,sdfit)`. But an exact solution is more complicated since you now have to specify not only a functional form of mean(wt)~mean(age), but also for the variance.